# Javascript sleep code running, but seems to not cause any delays

Tags: node.js, angular

This an Angular app, and this specific code is inside a webworker in Typescript. I'm still new to webworkers, but both the sleep and the loop execute inside the same thread.

The intent is to poll a service and exit the loop when a the process is completed. My problem is the sleep call below is not sleeping. I need it to delay for at least 9 seconds, and ideally I'd like it to be configurable. But it runs as though the sleep didn't run.

I have two questions:

1. Why is the sleep not working?
2. This is an Angular app served by a NodeJS container on cirrus. When the Angular app is requested and served by this NodeJS server, I'd like to pass a secret defined at the NodeJS server along with the Angular app. This secret would be the polling delay. Would a cookie value be returned in the NodeJS Angular App response? Not sure what the best response would be.

Code below:

```
function sleep(ms: number) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        log('DEBUG','Sleeping for ' + ms + ' ms');
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}

while (jobIsStillRunning(jobExecutionResult)) {
    postMessageWithLog(jobExecutionResult);
    log('DEBUG','sendFilePolling() jobExecutionResult=' + JSON.stringify(jobExecutionResult));
    sleep(30000);  // Sleep function runs but doesn't do anything.
    jobExecutionResult = await getAsyncFilesResult(jobExecutionResult);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to await on `sleep` function

Comment: Do I "await" on the call to the sleep method() or add an await keyword on the sleep prototype?

Comment: you need await on sleep method only as sleep return a promise, you should await on it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to know `macro` and `micro` tasks.

`Microtasks` come solely from our code. They are usually created by promises: an execution of `.then/catch/finally` handler becomes a microtask

If a microtask recursively queues other microtasks, it might take a long time until the next macrotask is processed. This means, you could end up with a blocked UI, or some finished I/O idling in your application.

example:

`macrotasks`: setTimeout, setInterval, setImmediate, I/O, UI rendering, etc/

`microtasks`: process.nextTick, Promises, etc.

code:

```
console.log('1')

setTimeout(()=>{
  console.log('2')
},0)

Promise.resolve().then(()=>{
  console.log('3')
})

console.log('4')
```

output:

```
1
4
3
2
```

wait what?!

explain:

- `console.log('1')` it's a normal code and immediately run.
- `setTimeout` it's a macrotask then it will add to macro queue
- `Promise.resolve` it's a microtask then it will add to micro queue
- `console.log('4')` it a normal code and immediately run.

now when normal codes are end and now `microtaskqueue` and `macrotaskqueue` need to be dequeue.

- inside `microtaskqueue` we have one task and it's `Promise.resolve` then immediately run `.then` function

now `microtaskqueue` is clear too, inside `macrotaskqueue` we have one task and it's `setTimeout` then immediately run `timeoutCallback` function

if you want to use `sleep` function without `await` you need to handle this.
but you can add `await` before your `sleep` function and wait on it